# Calling Objective-C methods from RubyMotion - not precompiled error

Tags: rubymotion

When trying to call an Objective-C method that has NSUInteger arguments from RubyMotion I get the following error:

```
`@@:I' not precompiled. Make sure you properly link with the framework or 
 library that defines this message.
```

This happens with any method that has NSUInteger/NSInteger/int arguments, but it works fine for methods that take NSString* arguments or methods that have no arguments. This is using RubyMotion 2.24 and iOS 7.1.

This is related to a new RubyMotion project which is for testing code in a Cocoa Touch Static Library.

Any thoughts or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a misunderstanding of how BridgeSupport files worked. I hadn't generated one for my library but one was being auto-generated by RubyMotion. I assumed it was automatically loading that when running my app but it wasn't.

After I added the appropriate it worked:

```
app.bridgesupport_files << "path/to/...bridgesupport"
```

I have since my library target in XCode to generate the bridgesupport file whenever its built. I've put it all in a gist.

https://gist.github.com/zdennis/9608082